# What is FUSE_NOTIFY_CODE_MAX and why it is not initialized?

Tags: c++, fuse

I'm studying sources of the FUSE to get a general understanding of how it works. Unfortunately I'm not a C++ programmer which makes the task harder. I have found this struct in `fuse_kernel.h` and don't understand it's element purpose. What is FUSE_NOTIFY_CODE_MAX and why it is not initialized?

```
enum fuse_notify_code {
  FUSE_NOTIFY_POLL   = 1,
  FUSE_NOTIFY_INVAL_INODE = 2,
  FUSE_NOTIFY_INVAL_ENTRY = 3,
  FUSE_NOTIFY_STORE = 4,
  FUSE_NOTIFY_RETRIEVE = 5,
  FUSE_NOTIFY_DELETE = 6,
  FUSE_NOTIFY_CODE_MAX,
};
```

Comment: [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) has a good explanation of the default value assignment for `enum`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the largest value that the enumeration has, and it **is** initialised, although not explicitly:

If you don't specify an explicit value for an enumeration, then it takes a value of one greater than the previous one in the list. (If an enumeration has no explicit values then the first eumeration will have a value of zero).

It's rather nice that the author of the enumeration has not hardcoded that number.

Comment: It is interesting that the author is assigning a value to all of the other enumerations.  You would think they would not to save some typing and to make sure thy don't accidentally assign a value that would make the max not the max.